# If $\frac{9^n \cdot 3^2 \cdot (3 ^ {-n/2})^{-2} - 27^n }{3^{3m} \cdot 2^3} = \frac{1}{27} $. Prove that $m - n = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have tried the above sum but in the end I got something like

$$\frac{3^{6n + 2}}{3m} = \frac{8}{27}$$

I don't think it is correct because I cant go any further to prove what is required to prove.
Need Help.

Comment: please use mathjax  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: Something is off in what you've done. Basically, the $2^3 = 8$ has to cancel with an $8$ directly coming from the top, leaving you with powers of three either side, then compare exponents.

Comment: You have messed up your exponent rules I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{3^{2n+2}\cdot 3^n-3^{3n}}{3^{3m}\cdot 8}=3^{-3} \implies 3^{3n-3m}=3^{-3} \implies m-n=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{9^n\cdot3^2\cdot\left(3^{\frac{-n}2}\right)^{-2}-27^n}{3^{3m}\cdot2^3}=\frac1{27}$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{9\cdot3^{2n}\cdot3^n-3^{3n}}{8\cdot3^{3m}}=\frac1{27}$$

$$\Rightarrow9\cdot3^{3n}-3^{3n}=\frac{8\cdot3^{3m}}{27}$$

$$\Rightarrow8\cdot3^{3n}=\frac{8\cdot3^{3m}}{27}$$

$$\Rightarrow3^{3n}=\frac{3^{3m}}{27}$$

Now take the logarithm base $3$.